# How to authorize HttpClient for TFS

Tags: authentication, tfs, httpclient

I received this output when trying to access the commits in TFS:
The uri works in my browser, but the authentication is not working for my httpClient. My username is domain\user, and right now I'm only using the user part of my username, but I've tried it with and without the domain. Please help!

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

```
try 
{ 
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                        = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));


    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows authentication and you're logged in using the correct account already, you don't need to provide an Authentication header.

Instead of `var httpClient = new HttpClient();`, write

`var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to replace `var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");` with below format (It works on my side):

```
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "domain\\username", "pasword"));
```

Sample here:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetCommits
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Task t = GetCommits();
            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t });
        }
        private static async Task GetCommits()
        {
            try
            {
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();

                var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "domain\\username", "password"));

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                                    = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));


                var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://ictfs2015:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Git-Scrum/_apis/git/repositories/389e8215-1fb2-4fdc-bd04-ebc8a8a4410e/commits/a395accfe2f1ed60ee404d6515fc9f55631cbe42");
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```